# summary() is taking an age to compile the output for lmer model. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Tags: r, lme4

I am fitting a maximal model to untransformed response times to correct trials, with two, two-level, centered categorical predictors (Stimulation, Cognate Status) and an orthogonal second-order polynomial with 5 levels (Block). Random effects include full crossed structure with correlations. 32 subjects, 60 items, balanced, within-subjects design, 12,406 observations. The model converges but the summary takes an age to process.

The model runs without any convergence issues but summary() initialises a memory-intensive process but does not compile/print the output. I don't have any issues with the summary() function for any other elements.

I have included the code for the model for reference.

```
    Max.lmer.RT = lmer(RT ~ StimCent.r*(ot1 + ot2)*CogStatCent.r + 
                  (1 + StimCent.r*(ot1 + ot2)*CogStatCent.r | PID) + 
                  (1 + StimCent.r*(ot1 + ot2) | DutchName:CogStatCent.r), 
                  data = TDL.cent.RT, REML = FALSE, control = 
                  lmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap2", optCtrl =  
                  list(maxfun = 100000)))   

    summary(Max.lmer.RT)
```

A fix or suggestions on what might be causing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using `lmerTest` ?

Comment: Yes, I guess it had masked lme4, so it is probably to do with the estimates of parameter-specific p-values (and a touch of impatience)?

Comment: computing the Kenward-Roger approximation for the degrees of freedom takes a long time, but I'm a little puzzled because the default (IIRC) df calculation is Satterthwaite, which shouldn't be that expensive ... I think the problem here is in `lmerTest:::calcApvar`, which recomputes the Hessian by finite differentiation - this could be expensive in a many-parameter problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. With a little more patience and by saving the summaries as objects I get the output in the end. Taking the parsimonious approach from Bates et al. (2015) ZCP and refitted models produce the summary within reasonable time frame in any case.

Comment: You can use `merTools::fastdisp` to produce a model summary with just parameters of interest without recomputing the deviance too.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup jknowles